# JavaFX tableview clears collection

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I have a tableview and what I am trying to do is based on a radio button that has environment types; QA, DEV, PROD, etc.. It adds an observable list to the table view, and if you click a different radio button it clears that list of the previous environment and shows the associated observable list within the tableview.

My problem is that since the obs list is passed by reference into the tableview,
tableview.getItems().clear() clears the tableview and the list. I'm trying to make it so that -- it only clears the content showing in the tableview and not the original list.

```
ObservableList<BarFile> devCheckboxList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
//List gets populated with files elsewhere
                    switch (chk.getText()) {
                    //Check to see which checkbox is selected
                    case "DEV":
                        tableView.getItems().clear();
                        System.err.println("DEV IS TRUE");
                        environmentCheck("DEV");
                        //Add to listview
                        tableView.setItems(devCheckboxList);
                        break;
}
```

[Populated Tableview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Heg5t.png)

[Tableview when environment is switched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xDS9.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to clear the existing list, just don't call `clear()`:

```
ObservableList<BarFile> devCheckboxList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
//List gets populated with files elsewhere

    switch (chk.getText()) {
    //Check to see which checkbox is selected
    case "DEV":
        // tableView.getItems().clear();
        System.err.println("DEV IS TRUE");
        environmentCheck("DEV");
        //Add to listview
        tableView.setItems(devCheckboxList);
        break;

}
```

Since you are replacing the table's entire list anyway, the call to `clear()` has no effect on what is displayed in the table.